# MatchType in Android Firebase Dynamic Link SDK

Tags: android, firebase

I'm implementing a Firebase dynamic link mechanism in Android. We wanted to use Android SDK but to match users only when there is a one-to-one identification between users who clicks the link and user, which opened the app. 
In iOS there is MatchType.Unique that serves this purpose:

> The match between the Dynamic Link and this device is exact, hence you may reveal personal information related to the Dynamic Link.
>   https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedynamiclinks/api/reference/Enums/DLMatchType#unique

Unfortunately, I can't find anything close in Android SDK. 
I will appreciate any help here to find how to distinguish deep links of the unique match type in Android

Thanks

Comment: I would like to help but am having a hard time understanding what you are looking for. Might you be able to rephrase the question? Use steps such as 1. Dynamic link is sent 2. Some user tries to open link in app 3. If link was intended for said user, then show personal data. 4. If the wrong user clicked to open the link do not show personal data. AND if I am correct so far,  what does it mean to be the wrong user? Is the link always intended for a single user? Or can multiple user accounts be deemed right/correct users?

Comment: MatchType is only used to check either link opens first time or not, if it is unique (or default) then it must be first time, else it will return as week. Can you please explain more what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @Yonatan, Did you found any alternative for Android ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems from [this part of documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasedynamiclinks/api/reference/Enums/DLMatchType#unique) that the matchType parameter exists only in Swift.

Personally, what I did is creating an array saved in the SharedPreferences, of all the DynamicLink already handled. Then, I just need to check for all the DynamicLinks entering if they are part of this array, and ignoring them in such a case.

Seems that even after an hour, the last DynamicLink handled still remains kind of "active".